# Where to set up react router tags?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've read some answers here and it seems they are all replying to a specific problem. Mine more about usage and placement rather than a problem I am facing. I also read the documentation but it does not answer my question.

My question is **where** to use react-router components?

1. Do I import (and use) `BrowserRouter` in index.js or App.js or does it go wherever the navigation bar is?
2. Do `Route`, `Switch`, `NavLink`, `Link` must be in the same module/file? If not, do I use them around the navigation bar element?
3. On the official website it shows that `<Switch>` is INCLUDED within `<BrowserRouter>` tags AFTER `<Link>` elements were used. Can I conclude from that `<Switch>` always come in the same element where `<Link>` elements were used?

I am beyond confused as to where these tags should be used in relation to other tags - **not how to get them to work**.

Finally, if I have a react app where index.js renders App.js. App.js is like a table of content of the main components I am rendering. Let's say: Header, Main, Footer. Inside the Header there are Greeting and then a NavigationBar. I want my links to be in the NavigationBar component as menu items. **Where** do I implement react-router components?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 . You can import and use BrowserRouter either in the root of the project which is index.js or in app.js just make sure it wraps around the Switch and Routes .

2 . The Switch Component must wrap all the Route components so this format is the most common way of using it :

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact component={<Component />} path="/" />
</Switch>
```

You can use NavLink or Link almost anywhere in your components which are imported in Route component prop .

NavLink and Link is just for navigating between Routes in your app .

And for the last part you can have a Layout.js component to have Header Main and Footer components inside of it wrap all the other components which are used in Routes for example :

```
index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

// Router
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
     ,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```
App.js

import React from "react";

// Router
import { Switch, Route, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

// Components
import Home from "./routes/Home/Home";

function App() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact component={Home} path="/" />
    </Switch>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
Home.js

import React from "react";

// Router
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

// Components
import Layout from "../../components/Layout/Layout";

function Home(props) {
  return (
    <Layout title="Homepage">

      <NavLink to="/ss">ss</NavLink>
    
      <NavLink to="/">/</NavLink> 
  
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Define Header Footer and Main in Layout.js :

```
Layout.js

import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

// Components
import Header from "../Header/Header";
import Footer from "../Footer/Footer";

function Layout({ title, children }) {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Helmet>
        <title>
          {title}
        </title>
      </Helmet>
      <Header />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
 
export default Layout;
```

The children prop is basically the Home.js component which has Layout wrapper so the Home.js component will display Header Footer from layout and it's own content .

This is the most common way of using the react-router-dom in a react project .

***Note***

The Switch component will only render the first route that matches/includes the path. Once it finds the first route that matches the path, it will not look for any other matches. Not only that, it allows for nested routes to work properly, which is something that Router will not be able to handle.

Fragment is just for wrapping the component tags like this :

```
import React , { Fragment } from 'react';

function Component() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Other />
      <Main />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

If you delete Fragment it will throw an error you can read more about Fragments [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) .

Comment: Why do use Switch with only one component (Home.js) in App.js? Why couldn't you put <Fragment> along with its children in App.js surrounded by <Switch>

Comment: Doesn't Switch look for the correct path if used with exact? Can you provide more details or references on this "Not only that, it allows for nested routes to work properly"? Why is this bad, and why can't Router handle? Thank you!